# Applying business logic in SELECT statement for a single field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table variable  in my stored procedure when executed gives the below result

```
SELECT * FROM @TableVariable

  Team  | Score | Change
  Team1    213      46
  Team2    244      51
  Team1    345      48
  Team2    256      45
  Team3    346      75
```

My stored procedure when executed should give the result in the below format.

```
SELECT T.[TeamName] as 'TeamName', @ScoreChange AS 'ScoreMetric', '' AS 'SeriesMetric'
FROM  dbo.[Team] T WHERE T.[OwnerId] = @OwnerId

 TeamName  | ScoreMetric | SeriesMetric
     Team1        34   
     Team2        34 
     Team3        34
```

The problem I have is with calculating `SeriesMetric`, because there is calculation involved while calculating the `SeriesMetric` and I need to embed that calculation logic in the below select query which is used in my stored proc

```
SELECT T.[TeamName] as 'TeamName', @ScoreChange AS 'ScoreMetric', '' AS 'SeriesMetric'
FROM  dbo.[Team] T WHERE T.[OwnerId] = @OwnerId
```

Below is the logic used to calculate 'SeriesMetric' which need to be embedded in the above select query

I need to group all the Teams in my Table variable @TableVariable and calculate the Average(Change) by team

Each team will have a ChangeAverage value

```
    Team     | ChangeAverage
    Team1          47
    Team2          48
    Team3          75
```

The 'SeriesMetric' for each team will be `ChangeAverage*100 / 25`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve that using window functions and partitioning i

```
SELECT 
 *
, AVG(Change) over (parition by Team) as  ChangeAverage
, (AVG(Change) over (parition by Team)) * 4 as SeriesMetric
FROM @TableVariable
```

But if you want to use it in combination with your other table to show your final result , here is what you need to do :

```
SELECT T.[TeamName] as 'TeamName'
, @ScoreChange AS 'ScoreMetric'
, AVG(TV.Change)* 4 AS 'SeriesMetric'
FROM  dbo.[Team] T 
LEFT JOIN @TableVariable TV
 on T.TeamName = TV.TeamName -- or whatever FK-PK is 

WHERE T.[OwnerId] = @OwnerId
GROUP BY 
T.NAME ,ScoreMetric
```